Write glTF Extension to Import Custom Animations
Summary: How can I use the extension mechanism of the glTF importer to read in my custom animation data and merge it into other actions created by the importer?
Background:
I'm using a custom extension to the glTF standard that stores custom animation data (the visibility of a node). After much confusion and fighting, I have written an extension to the glTF export/import add-on, and it writes the desired results. (Yay!) For the curious, here's an example of an animation in the glTF JSON that's using my extension. (You mostly don't need to understand the details for this question.)
{
  "name":"SlideZAndBlink",
  "channels":[
    {"sampler":0, "target":{"node":0, "path":"translation"}},
    {"sampler":1, "target":{
      "extensions":{
        "KHR_animation_pointer":{
          "pointer":"/nodes/0/extensions/EXT_node_visibility/visibility"
        }
      },
      "path":"pointer"
    }}
  ],
  "samplers":[
    {"input":6, "interpolation":"CUBICSPLINE", "output":7},
    {"input":8, "interpolation":"STEP", "output":9}
  ]
}

The important parts to note are that:

The extension references nodes by index, and
A single animation on a node might animate multiple properties (here, translation and visibility), some of which are not part of my extension, and
When multiple NLA Tracks in Blender have the same name, they are exported as a single glTF animation with channels that might target many different nodes.

Now I want to write the importer extension to round-trip this data. Unfortunately the documentation is quite sparse on how to use the extension capabilities of the add-on.
Through experimentation and diving into the source code, I believe this is the order of the callback hooks for the importer:
gather_import_gltf_before_hook
gather_import_scene_before_hook

for each node:
    gather_import_node_before_hook
    if node has a mesh:
        gather_import_mesh_before_hook
            gather_import_mesh_options
            for each primitive:
                gather_import_decode_primitive
            for each material:
                gather_import_material_before_hook
                gather_import_texture_before_hook
                gather_import_image_before_hook
                gather_import_image_after_hook
                gather_import_texture_after_hook
                gather_import_material_after_hook
        gather_import_mesh_after_hook

    else if it is a camera:
        gather_import_camera_before_hook
        gather_import_camera_after_hook

    else if it is a light:
        gather_import_light_before_hook
        gather_import_light_after_hook

    gather_import_node_after_hook

gather_import_scene_after_nodes_hook

gather_import_animations
for each animation:
    gather_import_animation_before_hook
    gather_import_animation_channel_before_hook
    gather_import_animation_channel_after_hook
    gather_import_animation_weight_before_hook
    gather_import_animation_weight_after_hook
    gather_import_animation_after_hook

gather_import_scene_after_animation_hook

My plan/implementation for the importer is:

Use gather_import_node_after_hook to keep track of which glTF node index turns into which Blender object:
def gather_import_node_after_hook(self, vnode, gltf_node, blender_object, gltf):
    self.object_by_node_index[vnode.mesh_node_idx] = blender_object

(Seems fragile, but also seems to work so far.)

Use gather_import_animations to loop through all the animations, find my extension data, and extract the info I need to decode:
def gather_import_animations(self, gltf_animations, animation_options, gltf):
    node_index_re = re.compile(r'^/nodes/(\d+)')
    for anim in gltf_animations:
        for channel in anim.channels:
            target = channel.target
            if target.path != 'pointer':
                continue

            for ext_name, data in target.extensions.items():
                if ext_name != khr_pointer_extension:
                    continue

                pointer = data.get("pointer")
                if not pointer or glTF_extension_name not in pointer:
                    continue

                node_index = int(node_index_re.match(pointer).group(1))
                blender_obj = self.object_by_node_index[node_index]
                sampler = anim.samplers[channel.sampler]
                self.vis_animations_to_add.append((blender_obj, anim.name, sampler))

(this step is also working as desired)

Sometime later, after the importer created all the other actions, go through the Blender scene, see if the blender_obj has an NLA Track with the right name already added; if so, add the FCurve data into it; it not, make a new action with the right name, and add FCurve data to that.
This is where I'm stuck.


The Question(s): Where in the importer extension am I supposed to be able to do this, and how am I supposed to modify the actions? Am I supposed to mutate some data structure during gather_import_animations, so the real importer does the work for me? Am I supposed to wait until gather_import_scene_after_animation_hook, and just use all bpy API to manually create the NLA tracks and actions, replicating code already in the importer add-on?
I lost a couple days trying to use the perfect-sounding BlenderNodeAnim.get_or_create_action() static method, before discovering that it was never meant for this purpose. I'm looking for guidance from anyone who has worked with this code base as to how an importer extension is supposed to elegantly integrate with the existing add-on.
